# Accessing RabbitMQ through webserver

Tags: apache, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a RabbitMQ server running on an EC2 instance, and a URL address pointing to the instance configured in Route53, which I use to access the RabbitMQ web UI.
I can access the UI just fine using Nginx or Apache, but when trying to look at the page of a specific queue or exchange I receive an error saying the object was not found. This behaviour does not happen when I access the UI directly through IP:Port url.

I've noticed this is a known bug, which was addressed here - 
https://fatalfailure.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-rabbitmq-mochiweb-server/

I've tried implementing the fix listed in this post, using the following Apache configuration -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName stage-rabbithq.apester.com 
    ServerAlias stage-rabbithq.apester.com
    ProxyPass /api http://localhost:15672/api nocanon
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:15672/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:15672/
</VirtualHost>
```

But the error prevails.
Does anybody have a solution for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, the problem was forgetting to add the following line to my site conf file -

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

Hope this helps someone, someday.